# Prove a set is at most countable.

Tags: real-analysis, summation

Let $X$=[0,1] denote the unit interval on the real line. Assume that $f:X \to X$ is a mapping such that $\sum_{x \in X}$ $f(x)$ $<$ $\infty$. Prove that the set {${x \in X  |  f(x) > 0}$} is at most countable.

I have no clue where to start with this problem.

Comment: You should probably tell us how you define sums whose index sets are infinite. I assume it is as follows: $$
\sum_{x\in X}f(x)=\sup\left\{ \sum_{x\in\hat{X}}f(x)\colon\hat{X}\text{ is  a finite subset of }X\right\} .
$$

Comment: @parsiad Yes this is the definition I am using.

Comment: How many $x$ can have $f(x) \geqslant \varepsilon$ for $\varepsilon > 0$?

Comment: @DanielFischer I am essentially trying to prove that only countably many such $x$ exist.

Comment: You're asking about $f(x) > 0$. As a step towards that goal, consider $f(x) \geqslant \varepsilon$ for some fixed $\varepsilon > 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E_{c}=\{x\in X\colon f(x)\geq c\}$.

Certainly, it is true that $E_{c}$ is finite for any $c>0$ since
otherwise we can find a sequence $(x_{n})_{n}$ such that $f(x_{n})\geq c$
for each $n$ and hence 
$$
\sum_{x\in X}f(x)\geq\sum_{n}f(x_{n})=\infty.
$$

Now, note that
$$
\left\{ x\in X\colon f(x)>0\right\} =\bigcup_{n}E_{1/n}.
$$
What can you conclude?

Comment: Since this set is a finite union of countable sets, it must also be countable. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. It's better, however, to use the weaker claim is that *a countable union of finite sets is countable*.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help!